# How to convert '19/7/2021 7:19' into date format by using anytime package in r?

Tags: r, anytime

I am trying to use anytime package in r to convert a character vector into date format.

However, this kind of format '19/7/2021 7:19' cannot be converted.

I tried to input the following code:

```
anytime::addFormats(c("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", "%Y/%d/%m %H:%M","%Y-%m-%d %H:%M","%d/%m/%Y %h:%M"))
```

And `NA` is returned.

Is there any way to solve this?

=============================================================
Update:
I used the following code to solve the problem:

```
f = anytime(ds5$MovementTime_)
h = strptime(ds5$MovementTime_, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
f[which(is.na(f)==1)] = h[which(is.na(f)==1)]
ds5$Movement_Time_clear = f
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is the single digit hour, your formats are expecting a double digit (i.e., 07, not 7).

Given your string pattern, simple solution would be to `gsub` to pad the 0, then `anytime::anytime()` after you add the format using `anytime::addFormats`:

```
# Before adding in format
anytime::anytime(gsub(" ", " 0","19/7/2021 7:19"))
# [1] NA

# after adding format:
anytime::addFormats("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M") 
anytime::anytime(gsub(" ", " 0","19/7/2021 7:19"))

# [1] "2021-07-19 07:19:00 SAST"
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Since the data includes different date formats, if I use `gsub` on the `date` vector, some elements may have excessive '0' appearing.

Comment: Gotcha - the `lubridate` package function `dmy_hm` may be a good option - `lubridate::dmy_hm("19/7/2021 7:19")` returns exactly what you want with no additional modifications

Answer (score 2):

Just like that.

```
date_str <- '19/7/2021 7:19'
date <- strptime(date_str, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
print(date)
```

If you like to keep the format as D-M-Y:

```
formatted_date <- format(date, format = "%d-%m-%y")
print(formatted_date)
```